# Welcome Email Notification with token and create password Link

Tags: laravel

i hope anyone can help me with this.
I am new to laravel and i want to add the Welcome Email Notification with token and Create Password Link in my Add User feature.
So it goes like this. After the admin create a user, an welcome email will be sent to the users email address together with the create password link and also a token.

I already make a welcome email notification but there is no token or link.

this is my controller

```
// Save New User
public function addNewUser(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'name'          => 'required|string|max:255',
        'email'         => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'role_name'     => 'required|string|max:255',
        'status'        => 'required|string|max:255',
        'image'         => 'required|image',
        'password'      => 'required|string|min:8|confirmed',
        'password_confirmation'     => 'required',
    ]);
    DB::beginTransaction();
    try{
        $dt             = Carbon::now();
        $todayDate      = $dt->toDayDateTimeString();

        $image = time().'.'.$request->image->extension();
        $request->image->move(public_path('/assets/images'), $image);

        $user = new User;
        $user->name             = $request->name;
        $user->email            = $request->email;
        $user->join_date        = $todayDate;
        $user->role_name        = $request->role_name;
        $user->status           = $request->status;
        $user->avatar           = $image;
        $user->password         = Hash::make($request->password);
        $user->save();
        DB::commit();

        $user->notify(new WelcomeEmailNotification());

        Toastr::success('Created Successfully','Success');
        return redirect()->route('userManagement');
    }catch(\Exception $e){
        DB::rollback();
        Toastr::error('User add new account fail','Error');
        return redirect()->back();
    }
}
```

and this is my Welcome Email Notification.php

```
/**
 * Create a new notification instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->user = $user;
}

/**
 * Get the notification's delivery channels.
 *
 * @param  mixed  $notifiable
 * @return array
 */
public function via($notifiable)
{
    return ['mail'];
}

/**
 * Get the mail representation of the notification.
 *
 * @param  mixed  $notifiable
 * @return \Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage
 */
public function toMail($notifiable)
{
    return (new MailMessage)
                ->line('The introduction to the notification.')
                ->action('Notification Action', url('/'))
                ->line('Thank you for using our application!');
}

/**
 * Get the array representation of the notification.
 *
 * @param  mixed  $notifiable
 * @return array
 */
public function toArray($notifiable)
{
    return [
        //
    ];
}
```

}

Comment: Have you installed the `laravel/ui` package? It has this functionality built-in. If you don't want to use their implementation, you can look at their code to see how they accomplish the same thing. Regardless, this question is far too unfocused to be properly answered here.

Comment: create a 60 character random string as $token, encrypt it and write it to the password_resets table along with the user email address and the current timestamp.  Then notify your user using url `route('password.reset', $token}`